# Using LINQ for JOINs and Sum

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I just started working with LINQ. How can I use SUM and LEFT JOIN using LINQ. I am trying to build the query below in LINQ. Is it possible?

```
SELECT t.TenantID, t.TenantFName, t.TenantLName, t.RentalAmount, t.PetRent, t.HousingAmount, t.UtilityCharge, t.TVCharge, t.SecurityDeposit, t.HOAFee,
   t.ParkingCharge, t.StorageCharge, t.ConcessionAmount, t.ConcessionReason, t.TenantEmail, t.TenantPhone, t.CellPhoneProviderID, t.MoveInDate,
   p.PropertyID, p.PropertyName,
   TotalDebit, HousingDebit, TotalCredit, HousingCredit
  FROM Tenants t
  JOIN Properties p ON t.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
  LEFT JOIN (
        Select
          TenantID,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 AND TenantTransactionDate <= Now() THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDebit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 AND TenantTransactionDate <= Now() THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingDebit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 AND TenantTransactionDate <= Now() THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCredit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 AND TenantTransactionDate <= Now() THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingCredit
        From TenantTransactions
       Group By TenantID
       ) sums ON sums.TenantID = t.TenantID
 Where t.Prospect = 2
   AND t.PropertyID = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you purely asking whether it's possible or for a rough LINQ example?  Looking at it I don't see any reason why you could turn that into a LINQ statement(s).  I'd probably do it in a series of steps for clarity.

Comment: Isn't better has do just one query to the database instead of a series of steps/queries?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't necessarily be making multiple calls to the database.  Query construction is separate from query execution.  You can construct your query in a series of steps and the call to the database would only occur when you attempt to iterate over the query.  Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution, it explains the concept better than I.  Although even if you did make multiple calls to the database, it usually isn't *that* bad, but it depends on your database.

Comment: Thanks... Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Possible post with C# models and sample data, desired output.

Comment: That's the problem. I do not know how to do the LEFT JOIN with the SUM as show in the SQL using LINQ

Answer (score 1):

I used classes to model you database.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tenants> tenants = new List<Tenants>();
            List<Properties> properties = new List<Properties>();
            List<TenantTransactions> transactions = new List<TenantTransactions>();


            var tenantTransactions = transactions.GroupBy(x => x.TenantID).Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.Key,
                totalDebit = x.Where(y => (y.TransactionTypeID == 1) && (y.ChargeTypeID != 6) && (y.TenantTransactionDate <= DateTime.Now)).Sum(y => y.TransactionAmount),
                housingDebit = x.Where(y => (y.TransactionTypeID == 1) && (y.ChargeTypeID == 6) && (y.TenantTransactionDate <= DateTime.Now)).Sum(y => y.TransactionAmount),
                totalCredit = x.Where(y => (y.TransactionTypeID == 2) && (y.ChargeTypeID != 6) && (y.TenantTransactionDate <= DateTime.Now)).Sum(y => y.TransactionAmount),
                housingCredit = x.Where(y => (y.TransactionTypeID == 2) && (y.ChargeTypeID == 6) && (y.TenantTransactionDate <= DateTime.Now)).Sum(y => y.TransactionAmount)
            }).ToList();

            var results2 = (from t in tenants
                           join p in properties on t.PropertyID equals p.PropertyID
                           join tt in tenantTransactions on t.TenantID equals tt.id into ps
                           from tt in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { t = t, p = p, tt = tt })
              .Where(x => (x.t.PropertyID == 1) && (x.t.Prospect == 1))
              .GroupBy(x => x.t.TenantID)
              .Select(x => new {
                  tenantID = x.Key,
                  tenantFirstName = x.FirstOrDefault().t.TenantFName,
                  tenantLastName = x.FirstOrDefault().t.TenantLName,
                  tenantEmail = x.FirstOrDefault().t.TenantEmail,
                  tenantPhone = x.FirstOrDefault().t.TenantPhone,
                  tenantCellPhoneProvider = x.FirstOrDefault().t.CellPhoneProviderID,
                  properties = x.Select(y => new {
                     propertyID = y.p.PropertyID,
                     propertyName = y.p.PropertyName,
                     rentalAmount = y.t.RentalAmount,
                     petRent = y.t.PetRent,
                     houseingAmount = y.t.HousingAmount,
                     utilityCharge = y.t.UtilityCharge,
                     tvCharge = y.t.TVCharge,
                     sercurityDeposit = y.t.SecurityDeposit,
                     hoaFee = y.t.HousingAmount,
                     parkingCharge = y.t.ParkingCharge,
                     storageCharge = y.t.StorageCharge,
                     concessionAmount = y.t.ConcessionAmount,
                     concessionReason = y.t.ConcessionReason,
                     tenantMoveInDate =  y.t.MoveInDate
                  }).ToList(),
                  totalDebit = x.FirstOrDefault().tt.totalDebit,
                  housingDebit = x.FirstOrDefault().tt.housingDebit,
                  totalCredit = x.FirstOrDefault().tt.totalCredit,
                  housingCredit = x.FirstOrDefault().tt.housingCredit,
              }).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class TenantTransactions
    {
        public int TenantID { get; set; }
        public int TransactionTypeID{ get;set;}
        public int ChargeTypeID { get;set;}
        public DateTime TenantTransactionDate { get;set;}
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get;set;}
    }
    public class Tenants
    {
        public int PropertyID { get; set; }
        public int Prospect { get; set; }
        public int TenantID { get; set; }
        public string TenantFName { get; set; }
        public string TenantLName { get; set; }
        public decimal RentalAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal PetRent { get; set; }
        public decimal HousingAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal UtilityCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal TVCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal SecurityDeposit { get; set; }
        public decimal HOAFee { get; set; }
        public decimal ParkingCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal StorageCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal ConcessionAmount { get; set; }
        public string ConcessionReason { get; set; }
        public string TenantEmail { get; set; }
        public string TenantPhone { get; set; }
        public string CellPhoneProviderID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MoveInDate { get; set; }

    }
    public class Properties
    {
        public int PropertyID { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting timeout exception.

Comment: The Command contains a timeout which defaults to 30 seconds.  It needs to be increased.  SQLite is not a very fast database.  It uses a SDF file and speed is function of the file size and the amount of memory on your computer.  When all the memory is used up the data is put into a cache in a temporary file on your computer which slows the process a lot.  I will see if I can modify query to reduce memory.

Comment: A tenant can be renting more than one property which adds some complication.  I updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Roughing out an answer and making a few assumptions about your object model, I'd start off by calculating each of the sums individually with something akin to this statement:

`var tenantsTotalDebit = tenantTransactions.Where(tt.TenantId == requestedTenantId && tt.TransactionTypeID == 1 && tt.ChargeTypeID != 6 && tt.TenantTransactionDate <= DateTime.Now).Select(tt => tt.TransactionAmount).Sum();`

After you've got all the sums, you can create another query that queries the `Tenants` and, assuming the `Tenants` object has it's associated `Properties` as a member, you could combine them in something like this:

`var tenantQuery = tenants.Where(t.Prospect == 1 && t.PropertyID ==1).Select(t.TenantID, t.TenantFName, ..., tenantsTotalDebit, tenantsHousingDebit, tenantsTotalCredit, tenantsHousingCredit);`

You can include values beyond the object type that you're querying in a `Select()` method, so you can include the precalculated sums after determining them separately.

Comment: var tenantsTotalDebit is returning one record. It should be a sum of tenanttransactions.TransactionAmount

Comment: @MaxBoy ah, valid point.  Updated that query to select the correct value and sum them.  Again, don't know your exact model so this is a rough outline of how you could approach it.